# Converting escape sequences to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Javascript has some escape sequences for it's strings, including `\b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v, \0, \', \", \\`. Is there any built-in function to convert all appearings of these in a string to the HTML equivalent (`\n` to `<br>`, `\t` to `&nbsp`, etc) so I can use it like this `$('body').append('<div class="testing">' + escaped_string + '</div>');` and have it display correctly?

I have searched all over and people only seem to care about `\n` and `\t` and consequently all of the answers recommend using replace for that, but I want to avoid having to manually convert every one.

Thank you

EDIT: I was reading the string from an input and didn't remember the escape sequences would be taken as literal, that's why it wasn't being properly represented when rendered. I managed to escape it using `JSON.parse` on the read string combined with `white-space: pre-wrap;` in output CSS.

Comment: CSS: `white-space: pre-wrap;`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol doesn't work for the intended purpose, escape sequences are still interpreted as literal

Comment: *escape sequences are still interpreted as literal* what do you mean?  Do you see slash t slash n displayed in the output?

Comment: @james funny one. I mean I see `example \n example2`

Comment: In that case you have literal characters in your string and not escape sequences.

Comment: @James That's exacly it! the string is being read from an input and therefore \n is not interpreted as an escape sequence! I don't know how I didn't think of that... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and how to fix it! (Thank you for all your answers)

I didn't realize I was reading the string from an input and therefore the escape sequences were being interpreted as literal!

I managed to fix this by using `JSON.parse()`, turning the literals to escape sequences and now it is accurately represented using `white-space: pre-wrap;` the the output's CSS!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any built-in function to convert all appearings of these in a string to the HTML equivalent...?

No. That's why the answers you've found for it say to use `replace`. (That, and different people want to do different things when replacing newlines, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function, but you can just write a function by yourself in which you `replace` for each sign like `string.replace("\n", \"<br")` and so on. If you need help just send me a message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function, but you always can create one

```js
// Set string
const str = 'Hello\nthere! I\twant to be "HTML" friendly & pretty!';

// Set resulting html var
let html = '';

// Convert with your own rules
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  switch (str[i]){
      case '\n':
            html+="<br>";           
            break;
                
        case ' ':
            if(str[i-1] != ' ' && str[i-1] != '\t') html+=" ";                                                  
            break;
                    
        case '\t':
            html+="&nbsp";
            break;
                
        case '&':
            html+="&amp;";
            break;
                
        case '"':
            html+="&quot;";
            break;
                
        case '>':
            html+="&gt;";
            break;
                
        case '<':
            html+="&lt;";
            break;              
                
        default:
            html+=str[i];       
    }           
}

// Log
console.log(html);
```